# Rebinding in tcp is not happening with same port

Tags: c, tcp, port

In my project i want to open some port xxxx and need to write data and close that port XXXX.

Again i want to reopen same port and write data and closing. This what my requirement.

For first time i am able to write and close, but for second time binding is not happening. i don't why may be code issue or anything else.

Here is my code.

```
int main(void)
{
    int connection;
    int sock = create_socket(40056);
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    int len = sizeof(client_address);

    connection = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address,&len);
    close(connection);
    close(sock);
    sock = create_socket(40056);
    connection = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address,&len);
}

int create_socket(int port)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    int reuse = 1;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        PRINTF("socket creation failed...\r\n");
    }
    else
        PRINTF("Socket successfully created..\r\n");

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof reuse);

    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification
    if ((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) 
    !=0) //here typedef &servaddr
    {
       PRINTF("socket bind failed...\r\n");
    }
    else
       PRINTF("Socket successfully binded.. %d\r\n",port);

    listen(sockfd, 5);
    PRINTF("finished create socket function\r\n");
    return sockfd;
}
```

Comment: *"... binding is not happening. i don't why ..."* - what exactly do you mean with "not happening". Does the call to `bind` fail? If yes, what is the exact error you get (i.e. check `errno`, call `perror` or similar)? Also please check the return value of all functions you call, i.e. also check `setsockopt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`accept()` blocks as there are no pending connections. The relevant piece from [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) is:

```
       If no pending connections are present on the queue, and the socket is
       not marked as nonblocking, accept() blocks the caller until a
       connection is present.  If the socket is marked nonblocking and no
       pending connections are present on the queue, accept() fails with the
       error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.
```

You can mark the socket nonblocking with `fcntl()`, (optionally) add a call to perror (to get the "Resource temporarily unavailable"), and run your code to see the difference.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int create_socket(int port)
{
.
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
.
}

int main(void)
{
.
    connection = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address,&len);
    if (connection == -1) {
        perror("accept");
    }
.
}
```